# Error when Cognito tries to refresh credentials by itself

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am getting an error code that looks like this but don't really know why.

So up till this point i was using amazons end to end implementation of developer authentication. Everything seems to work but as soon as i try to use dynamodb to do something i get this error.

```
AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:528 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke352 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.service.cognitoidentity.DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider Code=0 "(null)"]
 The request failed. Error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.service.cognitoidentity.DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider Code=0 "(null)"]
```

Any help?

UPDATE 1: LOG OUTPUT FROM COGNITOSYNCDEMO
I removed out the information i thought should be private and replaced it with [redacted info]

```
2016-02-19 15:32:42.594 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] initializing clients...
2016-02-19 15:32:43.028 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] json: { "identityPoolId": "[redacted info]",    "identityId": "[redacted info]",    "token": "[redacted info]",}
2016-02-19 15:32:43.056 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] Error in registering for remote notifications. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
2016-02-19 15:32:54.449 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSCognitoSQLiteManager.m line:1455 | -[AWSCognitoSQLiteManager filePath] | Local database is: /Users/MrMacky/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/29BB1E0D-538D-4167-9069-C02A0628F1B3/data/Containers/Data/Application/1A86E139-5484-4F29-A3FD-25F81DE055EB/Documents/CognitoData.sqlite3
2016-02-19 15:32:54.451 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug] AWSCognitoSQLiteManager.m line:221 | __39-[AWSCognitoSQLiteManager getDatasets:]_block_invoke | query = 'SELECT Dataset, LastSyncCount, LastModified, ModifiedBy, CreationDate, DataStorage, RecordCount FROM CognitoMetadata WHERE IdentityId = ?'
2016-02-19 15:33:00.946 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] json: { "identityPoolId": "[redacted info]",    "identityId": "[redacted info]",    "token": "[redacted info]",}
2016-02-19 15:33:00.947 CognitoSyncDemo[2895:67542] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCognitoService.m line:215 | __36-[AWSCognito refreshDatasetMetadata]_block_invoke180 | Unable to list datasets: Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)"
```

Comment: It looks like it's failing to get credentials with which it would communicate with Dynamo. Have you tried the sync aspect of that sample app? If that's working, can you provide some snippet of how you're using the credentials  provider and the dynamo client?

Comment: Hey Jeff. So i tried the sync in the sample app and it doesn't appear to be working either. so i think your right. Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code = -4000 "(null)"           AND ERROR:                   AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCognitoService.m line:215 | __36-[AWSCognito refreshDatasetMetadata]_block_invoke180 | Unable to list datasets: Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)"

Comment: Which is weird to me because cognitoSyncDemo is returning to me a json file with my identityPool Id, identityID, and token all working correctly.

Comment: Can you update the post with the full stack trace? That is just the SDK wrapped error. A request ID might help as well.

Comment: Because it sounds like it's failing to get credentials at all. Most clients use a lazy loading of credentials - they don't try to get them until they need them. It'd be easier to diagnose if it was clear what the server is unhappy about.

Comment: I added an update to the cognitosyncdemo output

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception, it looks like you are trying to do push sync from the emulator. You cannot receive remote notifications on an Emulator.

Comment: Ah interesting. Well i did it from an actual device and still got an error of Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code = -4000 "(null)"

Comment: Am also getting this error "Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)", while syncing google plus login credentials in aws cognito. How to fix this any idea?